# Responsive Filemanager, Error uploading files. (Php)

Tags: php, responsive-filemanager

I've integrated the File-manager statically into my HTML document, and almost everything works fine except for the following:

When trying to upload images, in some cases it does not allow extension (bmp, tiff). While testing on another local server, only bmp.

With the videos something similar happens, I uploaded a video of 86 MB to 25-26 fps mp4 format and ok, and then uploaded one of the same format with 28 MB at 30 fps and says it does not support the extension.

It gives me the slight impression that has to do with some configuration of the server php.

Does anyone know why this happens?